# Order list by Date with split between future as past dates

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am getting records from a database using Linq to Entities as follows:

```
context.Orders.OrderBy(x => x.Schedule)
```

In this case I am ordering by DateTime Schedule ...

I would like to still order by DateTime Schedule but first I would like to show the ones which date is after today ad after it the ones which day are in the past.

How can I do this?

Comment: "Today" in which time zone?

Comment: @JonSkeet Today is DateTime.UtcNow

Comment: Well no, that's right now. A second ago may or may not still be today - depending on the time zone. Are you saying you're interested in the UTC time zone?

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo No reverse. I mean first appear the future dates starting with today ... After it appears the past dates ...

Comment: @JonSkeet Today would be current DateTime.Utc date part ... For this I can compare the dates with the available functions in EF. The problem is how to show first the future dates and after the past dates

Comment: For a bad title?! If you think so, please, do not criticize without suggesting a new one ... I will be happy to change it if you come with a better one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right, it sounds like you want something like:

```
DateTime startOfDay = DateTime.UtcNow.Date;
var results = context.Orders
                     .OrderBy(x => x.Schedule < startOfDay)
                     .ThenBy(x => x.Schedule);
```

That's assuming that EF still orders "false" before "true" - it would work in LINQ to Objects, certainly, but I don't know for sure in EF. Worth a try.

Comment: May be it will be better to get `Orders` table datas with `ToList()` and then to use `OrderBy` methods? Then it will work for sure.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev: Well the database is probably in a better position to do the ordering, if it works...

Comment: This seems to work fine in EF and avoid two queries to the database. The other option is not good for me because I am creating a PageList and I need to do this in one query

Comment: @JonSkeet Agree ... On call is better than 2 and makes possible to create a PagedList ...

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
 var AfterDates = context.Orders.OrderBy(x => x.Schedule).Where(y=> y.Schedule > DateTime.Now).ToList();
 var BeforeDates = context.Orders.OrderBy(x => x.Schedule).Where(y=> y.Schedule < DateTime.Now).ToList();
 // You can make another query for the Same Dates (excluded from my solution)
 // You can join these two lists if necessary
```

Now you have two ordered lists one for dates which are after today and one for ones which are before.